# Source code that read grub.conf while booting kernel

Tags: grub

I want to see the code which reads grub.conf, googled but not found.
From below link what I understand that /boot/grub/stage2 reads grub.conf, which is a binary file.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E41138/html/ch04s02.html

> Stage 2 Stage 2 code reads /boot/grub/grub.conf to determine how to
>   load the kernel. The stage 2 code is stored in the file
>   /boot/grub/stage2:
>
> ls -al /boot/grub/stage2
>
> -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 125976 Jun 28  2012 /boot/grub/stage2

Any Idea where I can find it. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, one bit which could make finding the source code slightly confusing is that your grub is of the original instance, now known as "GRUB legacy".

Current development, and easily accessible source code, is all for what used to be known as GRUB2, and is now simply GRUB (with a version number >= 2). Development versions of GRUB2 were known as GRUB 1.9*.

So, I don't know if this is helpful at all, but to access old versions of GRUB sources, you can either look within your distribution packaging system, or in ftp://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/grub/.